# pass parameters to angular js directive partial view

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing

I have an MVC application using angularJS. I have a primary navigation and secondary navigation. I am using ngRoute for primary navigation. I made secondary navigation template a directive that I can use in all the other pages. The template used in the directive needs some input parameters.

Routing code:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/SecondaryNavigation/1', {
        templateUrl: 'administration/Page1',
        resolve: {                   
            SecNavItems: ["$http", function($http){
                var navItems = $http.get('/Navigation/SecondaryNavigation', {params: { pageName:            'Administration'}});
                navItems.success(function (data) {
                    return data;
                });
            }]
        },
        controller: 'AdminController'
})}]);

var AdminController = function ($scope, SecNavItems) {
$scope.secList = SecNavItems;
}

AdminController.$inject = ["$scope", "SecNavItems"];
myApp.controller("AdminController", AdminController);
```

Web method code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult SecondaryNavigation(string pageName)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> secnavItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        secnavItems.Add("1", "Item1");
        secnavItems.Add("2", "Item2");
        var navigationItemsJson = Json(secnavItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return navigationItemsJson;
    }
```

Page1 code is

```
<secondary-navigation></secondary-navigation>
```

My directive is defined as follows:

```
myApp.directive("secondaryNavigation", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: '/navigation/secondaryNavigation'
}
});
```

Partial view template:

```
<div style="height:100%; width:25%; background-color:#675c5c; color: white; float:left">
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> navItem in secList)
    {
        <a href="/#/@navItem.Key">@navItem.Value</a><br /><br />
    }
</div>
<div style="height:100%; width:75%; float:right"></div>
```

When I run the application I do not see the Item1 and Item2 in the page instead I see {{object}}

Please advise what I am missing in passing the parameters to the template used in the directive.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured what went wrong.

I had to create a html template of secondary navigation. I then included the web service call in the admincontroller, set the object value to the webservice result and added it to the routeProvider. I then 
set the scope to false in the directive.

Following are the changes I made.

Routing code:

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/SecondaryNavigation/1', {
        templateUrl: 'administration/Page1',
        controller: 'AdminController'
})}]);

var AdminController = function ($scope, $http) { 
            var navItems = $http.get('/Navigation/SecondaryNavigation', {params: { pageName:                'Administration'}});
            navItems.success(function (data) {
                $scope.secList = data;
            });
        }]
    },
}

AdminController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
myApp.controller("AdminController", AdminController);
```

My directive is defined as follows:

```
myApp.directive("secondaryNavigation", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    templateUrl: '/navigation/secondaryNavigation'
 }
});
```